# How to use Z3 SMT-LIB to solve equations in the Klein Group

Tags: z3

The table of products for the Klein Group is:

[image]

Using the following Z3 SMT-LIB code is possible to obtain a representation of the Klein Group:

```
(set-option :mbqi true)
(declare-sort S)
(declare-fun f (S S) S)
(declare-const a S)
(declare-const b S)
(declare-const c S)
(declare-const d S)
(assert (forall ((x S) (y S))
            (= (f x y)  (f y x))))
(assert (forall ((x S))
            (= (f x d) x)))
(assert (forall ((x S))
            (= (f x x) d)))                
(assert (= (f a b) c))
(assert (= (f a c) b))
(assert (= (f b c) a))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

and the corresponding output is:

```
sat 
(model 
;; universe for S: 
;; S!val!1 S!val!3 S!val!0 S!val!2
;; ----------- 
;; definitions for universe elements: 
(declare-fun S!val!1 () S) 
(declare-fun S!val!3 () S) 
(declare-fun S!val!0 () S) 
(declare-fun S!val!2 () S) 
;; cardinality constraint: 
(forall ((x S)) (or (= x S!val!1) (= x S!val!3) (= x S!val!0) (= x S!val!2))) 
;; ----------- 
(define-fun b () S S!val!1) 
(define-fun a () S S!val!0) 
(define-fun c () S S!val!2) 
(define-fun d () S S!val!3) 
(define-fun f ((x!1 S) (x!2 S)) S 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!2 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!2)) S!val!1 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!2)) S!val!0 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!2 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!2) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!1 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!2) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!0 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!3)) S!val!0 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!3) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!0 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!3) (= x!2 S!val!2)) S!val!2 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!2) (= x!2 S!val!3)) S!val!2 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!3)) S!val!1 
  (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!3) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!1 
  (ite (= x!2 x!1) S!val!3 x!1)))))))))))))) 
  )
```

Using this representation is possible to make computations in the Klein group:

```
(eval (f a b))
(eval (f (f a b) (f c d)))
(eval (f (f (f a b) (f c d)) (f (f a c) (f b d))))
```

and the corresponding results are:

```
S!val!2
S!val!3 
S!val!3
```

Run this example online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/QCuG)

The question is:  how to solve equations using this representation of the Klein group? In other words how to combine `assert` with `eval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a new input file containing the definitions in the model produced by Z3. For example, suppose we want to solve the equation

```
  x*a*b = a
```

We can create a new problem with the definitions produced by Z3, and the extra assertion

```
 (declare-const x S)
 (assert (= (f (f x a) b) a))
```

[Here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/j03q) is the full example.

We can also use the Z3 programmatic API to automate the whole process (and avoid the manual copy&paste).